# Is there a way to turn off Xcode indexing?

Tags: xcode

My project was originally a C makefile that I edit in Xcode. The source is a total of 127k and the Xcode project itself another 274k.

My DerivedData folder is 111.6 MB. 20 of that is the ModuleCache, another 91 is the Index. I am at a loss trying to understand how Xcode can turn 127k of source into 111 MB of indexes?!

Is there an *easy* way to turn all of this off and still have a functional editing environment?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understand your purpose. But to disable it, run this command in the terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable -bool true
```

To turn it on again, reverse to false.